# Do you have to have a thermostat for an electrical baseboard heater?

Tags: heating

Ours didn't come with a wall mounted thermostat! So do we need to buy one?

Answer (score 4):

You could just turn the breaker on when you are cold, and off when you are hot, I suppose. If that gets inconvenient, yes, you'd need a thermostat.

They do not normally "come with one" because one thermostat may control many heaters, or one thermostat and a bunch of relays may control even more heaters.

Some units **do** come with one built into one end of the baseboard itself, but that is a special option. You may be able to return the unit you have and get one like that if it would be more convenient in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You should check closely on one or the other end of your electrical baseboard heater units. Sometimes these come with a thermostat built right into the end of the unit.

It is a completely separate question as to whether a remote wall mounted thermostat is better than the one right on the heater unit. The wall thermostat can measure temperature away from the heater and probably achieve a better overall uniform temperature in the room.